# remove all .svn dirs recursively

Tags: svn, posix, msys

I found this solution:

`find -type d -name .svn|xargs rm -rf`

but I am on mingw environment (its bashy enough for me to deal with it anyhow) so I do not have the `find` command. I do however have use of `ls -aR` and such. Any tips?

Comment: why not jsut do an `svn export`?

Comment: well i don't know how to get svn on the command line on windows (use tortoisesvn). But it's true there's likely an option for it with tortoisesvn. I'll surely try this next time and i'm sure it will work like a charm. Doesn't hurt to know how to search out and destroy a specific type of hidden directory though.

Comment: Cygwin has got command line svn. I wouldn't use it on a tortoise checkout though, because they might not agree on line endings and the format of the .svn folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to install [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS), and install the findutils that it provides.

Comment: I think i did actually install MSYS. Probably need to do some more work to get the find command working?

Comment: I think you can install with `mingw-get install msys-findutils-bin`.

Answer (score 1):

`find.exe` is part of Msys(git). So is `xargs.exe` (not sure if it was with Mingw)

Alternatively, try Powershell ( you are on Windows afterall):

```
gci c:\path\to\workingcopy -include .svn -Recurse -Force | rm -Recurse -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

My half solution i ended up using:

```
ls -aR | egrep ".*.svn:" | sed s/.$// | xargs rm -rf
```

I will note that it failed to take care of one dir which had spaces in it, for the windows shell to handle that correctly it needed to have quotations (not sure if escaping the space works). Other than that it did work fine.

Better solutions that I should be using next time around:

1. `svn export`
2. getting find to work